# Spanned text in Number picker

Tags: android, kotlin, numberpicker, spanned

I have a problem with to show meter  **m<sup>2</sup>** in android. I can use SpannedBuilderString for setText in TextView and it work.

The problem is I want to show **m<sup>2</sup>** in Number Picker like 50 m<sup>2</sup> 100 m<sup>2</sup> but Number Picker only show String and I can't. Please help me fix that. Tks everyone.

Comment: sr for late reply, like I said in the question. I can setText with m<sup>2</sup> for textView just by `SpannableStringBuilder` and `superscriptSpan`. Because setText receive Spanned so my code work. But I don't see it in Number picker. Anyway, I found the solution using unicode of Tamir Abutbul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Unicode Character makes it very easy :

**First create an array with your values(this will go to the number picker)**

```
String mValues[] = { "100 " + "\u33A1", "200 " + "\u33A1" };
```

**Now use this method to create number picker with custom values:**

```
 private void setNubmerPicker(NumberPicker nubmerPicker,String [] numbers ){
    nubmerPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length-1);
    nubmerPicker.setMinValue(0);
    nubmerPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    nubmerPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
}
```

**And for the final step call this method:**

```
  setNubmerPicker(yourNumberPicker,mValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply this custom `Formatter` to your `NumberPicker`:

```
NumberPicker.Formatter formatter = new NumberPicker.Formatter(){
    @Override
    public String format(int i) {
        return  String.valueOf(i) + " " + Character.toString((char) 0x33A1);
    }
};

numberPicker.setFormatter(formatter);
```