# How to display more numbers in NumberPicker while scrolling

Tags: android, numberpicker

How to display more items/numbers in numberpicker while scrolling because its displaying only 3 numbers.Here is my code

```
 NumberPicker starttime = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.timeListview);

    starttime.setMaxValue(47);
    String[] time = {"12:00 AM", "12:30 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:30 AM", "02:00 AM", "02:30 AM", "03:00 AM","11:00 PM", "11:30 PM"};
    starttime.setDisplayedValues(time);
    starttime.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: I think this is not possible with Native `NumberPicker` widget .

Comment: Could try, numberPicker.setWheelItemCount(5)

Comment: @ADM Do you know any other method how to display more elements and making middle element focused while scrolling without using NumberPicker?

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman Rana Its not working

Comment: Well you can use a third party library if you can Like [This one](https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/PickerView) i found on first search.

Comment: @pratival could you please try, np_wheelItemCount, for reference please follow - https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code please try this it will help

```
NumberPicker starttime = findViewById(R.id.timeListview);
String[] time = {"12:00 AM", "12:30 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:30 AM", "02:00 AM", "02:30 AM", "03:00 AM","11:00 PM", "11:30 PM"};
    starttime.setMinValue(0);
    starttime.setMaxValue(time.length-1);
    starttime.setDisplayedValues(time);
    starttime.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: I used your modified code its not working only 3 items are displaying

Comment: @partival you need to share a bit more code, Sandeep solution is a good solution, refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53467327/8274756) to see that this is working.and if this solution is working you have other problem - but we need code to help you